# What should our logo and site design be like?

Tags: discussion, beta-essentials

Although we haven’t made much progress on the domain name discussion, I don’t think it necessarily too soon to start talking about site design and logo ideas. Does anyone have any strong ideas about what visual elements our site about English Language and Usage should have?

Comment: I wonder if there's any chance that we could have a world-class logo designer among us... ;-)

Comment: @RegDwight: There is a professional designer on the stackexchange team who will do the design for the site if it gets through beta (note that one site has already been killed, so it is not guaranteed that this site will make it to a full-fledged site). He did the beta design which we're using now.

Comment: @Shinto: yeah, I am very much aware of [Jin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/53037/jin), and I am looking forward to seeing his ideas for this site. My previous comment was referencing (and reverencing) someone else, whose achievements in logo design are three clicks away from Jin's page.

Comment: @RegDwight I appreciate the oblique reference (and reverence) but my logo designing hat has long been retired, for there is nowhere to go but down from there.

Comment: I figured as much. Again, this was more of a "Hats off!" than a "You go do it, class dismissed!".

Answer (score 5):

Just to throw some ideas out there, a few possible theme directions — I don't necessarily even like these ideas as-is (as-are?), but maybe they will get the ball rolling and lead to better ideas:

- dictionary-ish style, e.g. a classic serif font for the title and menus (probably serif everywhere would be overkill), maybe some IPA, part-of-speech, definition stuff sprinkled here and there
- etymology theme, e.g. Germanic branch of the language tree, Old English/Middle English
- revision theme, e.g. [stuff like this](http://www.colorado.edu/Publications/styleguide/symbols.html)

I am trying to think of more abstract visual themes, but we're talking about language, so nothing obvious comes to mind.

#### Note: these have been split into individual entries in case people want to vote on them.

Comment: I like the etymology and revision themes.

Comment: I'm very fond of the historical option!

Comment: I like the dictionary-ish style the best, but I like all three options.

Comment: Suggestion: split these into separate answers so that people can vote on them individually.

Comment: Good idea.  I will do that.

Answer (score 5):

Dictionary-ish style, e.g. a classic serif font for the title and menus (probably serif everywhere would be overkill), maybe some IPA, part-of-speech, definition stuff sprinkled here and there

Answer (score 2):

Revision theme, e.g. [stuff like this](http://www.colorado.edu/Publications/styleguide/symbols.html)

Answer (score 0):

Etymology theme, e.g. Germanic branch of the language tree, Old English/Middle English